# Boot failure after updating to grub2

Tags: fedora

I am getting the grub prompt on my machine. I know that I can use the information at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2 to reboot but I don´t know where the fedora linux partition is located on the harddrive. How can I find the information regarding /dev/sda etc in the grub prompt?

I tried the commands in the above URL concerning the grub prompt but I keep ending on a black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LiveCD distribution of your favourite distro and boot from it. Then use tools like fdisk or gparted to locate your Fedora Linux partition. After that you can [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) inside your Fedora partition and repair your grub using grub-mkconfig or manually.

Comment: Not to sound backward, but once in the live CD OS, what commands would you use to find the part of the harddrive (sda2, sad3 etc)?

Comment: @stars83butts: `sudo blkid` will list the devices and their labels/uuids.

Comment: @stars83clouds, you can just use GParted - it is GUI-based application, so just install it with your package manager and run